# Inviting experts

Tags: discussion

We're getting a lot of great questions now Alhamdulillah. But we need experts to answer them! Whenever you see a question and you know someone who is knowledgeable and can answer it, send the question to them. This is a template that I use (after greetings and a short personal message):

> I'm trying to get some experts involved in a Stack Exchange Q&A website on Islam. I'm not sure if you're familiar with the Stack Exchange network of websites - they are a set of extremely high-quality Q&A websites. The ones that I was involved in earlier, in particular, have a number of experts asking and answering expert-level questions in their respective fields. There are professors and researchers who are active on these sites. You can view some of them here: http://stackexchange.com/sites .
>
> The point is that these websites are very highly ranked repositories of information for their fields. A Q&A for Islam just started, and like I said we're trying to recruit experts to answer some questions there and raise the quality. Here are a couple that I thought you might be able to help out with:
>
> <links to some questions>
>
> The community upvotes answers that are well-written, focused, and well-referenced. It's not a fiqh or fatwa website - it's an information website. The reason I'm trying to get people involved is that Stack Exchange websites are VERY highly ranked on Google - when someone searches for the topic or content of anything, SE websites are usually on the first page. It would be great da'wah to get a solid and scholarly voice on there InshaAllah. A good number of people are participating already Alhamdulillah - but we need people like you to take it to the next level.

Send these emails liberally to scholars, students of knowledge, academics, and other experts you know! Maybe 1 in 5 will actually take the time to answer it, but that's one more expert for the site.

This is a critical moment for the website - we're getting good questions, and the quality of the answers those questions get will set the tone for our website.

As a side note, I'm going to ask that people refrain from answering a question if it's not in their area of expertise. On Stack Exchange (and in Islam!), saying nothing is better than saying something that you're not sure of or something that doesn't quite answer the question.

Comment: I will invite my friends from the Mosque to join. Allahu Akbar.

Comment: Same is my opinion too. To make a good place of questions and answers of islam, we must try to get the authentic informaration from the experts, OR as many islamic scholar's(Maulana, Hafiz, Mufti's) are not used to the internet, we can get the answer's from them and post them here, by correctly referencing them.