# How can we prove an inquiry historically?

Tags: discussion

In the question below, the questioner inquired  Did Yazid order to kill Imam Hussein (a.s)? and it would prove it historically. (by historical proof). But a moderator (gold Pseudo) put the answers on hold.

https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/18945/did-yazid-order-to-kill-imam-hossein-a-s/

In the answers of the respondents, they have mentioned historical narrations and likewise the speech of Yazid (about a letter…), to prove (historically) that Yazid ordered..., such as Al-Dahabi, Al-Suyuti, Musafi Ibn Sharih, Tzkiratul Khawas of Sibt Ibn Jauzi and so forth. And I reckon these were authentic and good enough to prove the issue.
But as I said, a moderator put it on hold, so I was wondering how we shall prove a matter by historical proof if these answers really are not appropriate?

Comment: It was closed with the reason of "unclear what you're asking"!!! I am looking forward to the answer.

Comment: Tis easy to answer every question (in meta), but the significant point is that "it ought to be answered logically, not attempt to find an excuse to justify.. Then hopefully we see some conscionable answers.

Comment: Please, realize that anybody and everybody can pour in their thoughts in a meta discussion. Not just a particular set of users. If the community supports the idea then the idea/suggestion could be used.

Comment: I know, your word is right as a rule of the site, but it ought to be performed practically. Besides this is very nice of you as a moderate moderator that see it positively. (tis my opinion)

Comment: A piece of advice, rather than fighting over the same and very same political reasons which were the cause of division of Sunnis and Shias, today in a more matured generation we can think of how Islamically we can unite. Please forget about the past. Previously, replies were given with swords, today we need to try stay united at least within the Muslim community.

Comment: Oh, yeah. To be honest, I am absolutely agree you about the issue of UNITY between Muslims. And unfortunately this matter is so weak nowadays between different Islamic countries ... insofar as... / God willing we see indeed good policy in the site concerning Unity (me & other good users) / God bless you for mentioning this significant issue.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I'm not convinced it's possible, at least not within the scope of this site.  "Proving" historical facts is a notoriously slippery beast at the best of times, and strongly veers into [apologetic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1255/22) territory which tends to drive away actual experts.  And in many cases where there are strong differences of opinion on the veracity of historical facts, such questions tend to become [Truth questions](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1442/22) driven by opinion, rather than being particularly practical or answerable.

What can or can not prove a claim is subjective depending on who is actually seeking the proof; there's no shortage of people rejecting "obvious" historical facts (e.g. people who deny that the holocaust or the moon-landing ever happened) simply because the sizable corpus of evidence doesn't meet their own criteria.  So, ultimately, the onus is on the questioner to not only know and ask for what will prove it to *them*, but to ask it in such a way that it's actually useful to more than exactly one person.

Such questions, unfortunately, are far more likely to attract vague lists of evidences rather than actual *answers*, again not particularly useful in the Stack Exchange model.

Of note, similar discussions have taken place on [History.SE](http://history.stackexchange.com), which perusal may also prove valuable here:

- [Relative truths and requests for examples](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/691)
- [What constitutes a request for a “List”](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/667)