# Closed Questions some are visible and some are not. How?

Tags: discussion, support

Title asks it all.

Take for e.g. [Is there any way to make Truth questions constructive?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1442/is-there-any-way-to-make-truth-questions-constructive) some questions in this are visible still on the site, and some are gone broken links. How does it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions may end up automatically deleted as per https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/132874, but they may also end up deleted by other users (including the original author) or moderators if they're considered to have no lasting value to the site. These deleted questions can still be seen by users who have earned the "[Access Moderator Tools](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)" privilege (2 000 reputation on beta sites, 10 000 reputation on graduated sites).  For users with insufficient reputation, they will only receive a page-not-found (unless it's their own post).

Deleted posts aren't actually *gone*; they can still be edited by anybody who can access them, and users with the Moderator Tools privilege can also vote to undelete them (except for posts deleted by a diamond moderator, which can only be undeleted by a diamond moderator) if they're later determined to be worth recovering.