# Why don't I get a chance to fix "offensive" language?

Tags: discussion, moderators, deleted-answer

In the following post I used a term "crazies" to describe people who corrupt religion. I could have removed it if I was asked to. Maybe the general answer is "offensive" but it is a valid answer, and if I need to reword it I would.

Since I lost virtually all of my rep because of this why wouldn't I get a chance to change it or remove it myself?

[Why do some Muslims refer to God as 'Allah' in English?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/326/why-do-some-muslims-refer-to-god-as-allah-in-english/29560#29560)

BTW, the definition of offensive is defined here and this post is not offensive:

[What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work)

Answer (score 4):

Oh, I'm sure you could have. But I think a better question you should be asking is, why would you expect anyone to give you the chance?

If I may quote the first line of your deleted post:

> Hahaha, I will tell you the true answer and get downvoted then deleted for it.

This line alone, to me, says not only that you posted your answer with the full intent of pushing Truth ([which is not what this site is for](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1591/22)) and/or tearing down those who disagree with you ([which is not what this site is for](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1255/22)), but that you did so with the full knowledge that doing so would be entirely unwelcome with this community. You went in *explicitly expecting* that your post would downvoted and then deleted, and now you're surprised that it *was*?

In the future, I would strongly recommend you take the time to write your posts in a [professional and respectful manner](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) that actually [*respects* the differences of opinion in Islam](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/275/22) instead of attacks them.

In other words, if you don't want your posts flagged for being offensive, just don't write offensive posts in the first place.

Comment: I was only making a joke, but perhaps I am pushing the truth instead of doing a researched answer. Yet, since this might not be an official view documented somewhere it could be impossible to create an answer because it would be a conclusion I draw instead of referencing someone else's conclusion. I guess you will always be able to delete something like this, and all answers should be simply repeating what others say. No "experience" based answers...thats not overly idealistic?

Comment: Wow, its not even close to the definition of offensive on stackexchange and I am right about voting before deleting. Oh, what a great job you do.