# Put on hold: Several most strong scientific proofs of trueness and scientifical weaknesses of Quran

Tags: discussion, moderation

https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36542/several-most-strong-scientific-proofs-of-trueness-of-quran
Several most strong scientific proofs of trueness of Quran
Write several most strong scientific proofs of trueness of Quran. I.e. from point of view of modern science.

https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36544/several-most-strong-scientifical-weaknesses-of-quran-and-how-do-you-solve-them
Several most strong scientifical weaknesses of Quran and how do you solve them
Write several most strong scientifical weaknesses of Quran and how do you solve them. I.e. write some things of Quran that looks wrong from point of view of modern science, and your scientific or logical defence for them.

Do you agree with GoldPseudo that these questions are opinion based?

2017-june-18: there is a similar question and it is not deleted: [How does one ensure the narrative of evolution is compatible with the Qu'ran?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/14521/how-does-one-ensure-the-narrative-of-evolution-is-compatible-with-the-quran) .

Answer (score 3):

Question 1:

> Write several most strong scientific proofs of trueness of Quran. I.e. from point of view of modern science.

Question 2:

> Write several most strong scientifical weaknesses of Quran and how do you solve them. I.e. write some things of Quran that looks wrong from point of view of modern science, and your scientific or logical defence for them.

Yes, they're opinion based---what is "strong" is a matter of opinion.  I also feel that both questions would also be reasonable candidates for closure due to lack of (indicated) effort.  ("What have you tried?")

Question 1 was asked here [Proof of Koran Authenticity](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/8681/17163) and has also been closed previously: (a) [How do you convince an atheist that Islam is the true religion?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30260/17163), (b) https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/23371/17163  Most of Question 1 answered here: (a) [What is the Islamic response to the atheist demand for 'proof' of God?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/635/17163), (b) [Why can't I find proof for Islam that I can see for myself?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/33442/17163)  Question 2 was mostly answered here: [Is it possible for the Qu'ran to have mistakes in it?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/25975/17163)

[WikiIslam](https://wikiislam.net/wiki/Islam_and_Science) offers a host of criticisms (many scientific) of the Qur'an and Islam in general.  I suggest going through those, and asking about specific criticisms you struggle to resolve.  (Note: WikiIslam is quite Islam critical.)

---

In addition to the above, an impartial scientist cannot begin with "how do you [re]solve them", which presupposes that the Qur'an is correct.  We would need to design an experiment which compares the accuracy of the Qur'an versus some baseline (e.g., the Bible, or the Harry Potter series).  The [null hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_hypothesis) would be that there is no more scientific support for the Qur'an than our baseline book(s).  Finally, as impartial scientists, we then would need to accept/reject the null hypothesis according to the evidence, ignoring our personal feelings and religious beliefs.

As a scientist and a Muslim, this does not strike me as the right approach.  Allah, if He chose to, could transcribe the Qur'an in the sky.  So I find it hard to believe He intends for us to worship Him based on a statistical significance test.

Comment: Why would you compare the quran to other religious/fictitious books, instead of comparing its claims about reality with reality? According to islam, there can't be a single error in the quran anywhere; seems like it should be judged against its own claims, not whether it is more or less accurate than other texts.

Comment: Not "instead of"---we compare both vs. reality.  We measure their consistency in some fair way, and test if the Qur'an is better than whatever baseline we chose.  (Without the baseline comparison, we have "evidence" like: the Qur'an states that men and women exist, which is consistent with reality.)

Comment: That just examines whether it is more accurate than whatever other text you compare it to. But the quran doesn't just claim to be less error-prone than other texts, it claims to be free of any error. To test that, you would see which claims it makes about reality - and there are many things in it about biology, physics, cosmology, geology, history, etc - and then you establish whether or not at least one of them is false.

Comment: I guess I have haven't addressed the idea of a "silver bullet" in my answer.  Ideas tend to be scrapped before the testing stage if they outright conflict with reality.  (Perhaps I'm biased too.)  Anyway, the main point is: could we reject the Qur'an depending on the results of a scientific experiment?  If no, then it's unscientific.

Comment: Falsifiability is the crucial point, I think you're right there. That is one major issues with those questions (and the answers to them), they look for confirmation, not failed attempts to falsify it.

Comment: " what is "strong" is a matter of opinion " - some proof can be more strong than other proof, because proofs may have mistakes/flaws.
" ... due to lack of (indicated) effort " - is effort done by questioner is required in this site?
" an impartial scientist cannot begin with "how do you [re]solve them" " - that is separate additional question just assuming most answerer here are muslims. if a non-believer answers, he could ignore that part of question.

Comment: " versus some baseline (e.g., the Bible, or the Harry Potter series) " - why you suggested bible and harry potter? did not i suggest view of modern science as baseline? but when comparing with modern science, quran should be accounted as not much detailed text, and some modern words could not be used in it, because ancient people would not understand them.

Comment: " So I find it hard to believe He intends for us to worship Him based on a statistical significance test " - god says many times in quran that he gives us "ayats" meaning not ayats of quran but facts of world. even if you believe god and quran without proofs, my questions are interesting questions.

Comment: " Question 1 was asked here Proof of Koran Authenticity " - ok, it is almost duplicate, and answers are not disabled, thank you. but i would like that there is also duplicate of the 2nd question.
" and asking about specific criticisms you struggle to resolve " - i wanted the most weak places to be shown so that readers can see that other statements of quran have less problems in checking and accepting them.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to quote a statement I've read in a booklet entitled "Koran and scientific research القرآن والبحث العلمي" by Idriss Kharchaf إدريس الخرشاف. In this book the author goes beyond the typical understanding and interpretation of Quran verses for example starting from verse ([67:19](http://legacy.quran.com/67/19)) he ends up discussing topics like the bird flue other examples can be found [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20573/islam-and-alien-mages/20575#20575).

The editor says: the problem with the so called inimitability of the Quran in science لإعجاز العلمي في القرآن is a delicate matter. We as Muslims consider the Quran as true and infallible while scientific discoveries and theories may be declared and refuted. So what would we do once we have declared that the Quran is going ahead with a theory if it got refuted?

So there's a big risk that by defending Quran as a scientific book one would contrarily give proof for it's falsehood that's why people shouldn't stick on this!

Quran isn't a book of science and shouldn't be considered as such it includes many vague descriptions which can widely be interpreted. However there are many Muslim "scientists" now who do research in this matter hoping to show the superiority of our Religion by interpreting verses of the Quran and ahadith or by searching for such texts in both to show that they go ahead with some scientific theories!

---

After this intro I'd like to answer your question more directly in a few words:

Both posts expect a list of either proof or scientific weaknesses ... that already means your Question is too broad (close reason). Now readers Muslim or non-Muslim would have different opinion on what is a weakness or a clear proof so yes these questions attract opinion-based answers. If you instead asked or questioned some of the weaknesses or proofs you had in mind that would be helpful as the question would be more focused which implies that the answers should have a similar focus.

And finally this site isn't meant to preach the truth ([How can we discourage users from using the site to preach Truth](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1591/how-can-we-discourage-users-from-using-the-site-to-preach-truth)), but to explain and give answers about Islam.

Comment: i say about modern science. it is concrete an quran is concrete, and for that, there are concete answers to my questions. also, answerers can use only very strongly proved things of science, that are unlikely to be refuted. "quran is not book of science" - it must conform some scientific criteria to be accepted by people, because it is not fantasy/fairy tale book, but it is normal documental/factual/scientific/argumentative/logical book.

Comment: "So there's a big risk that ... " - he can mistake/make error or not, but in fact that is actual situation with quran, and by banning that question you cannot change it.

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the question, it seems to contain only strategic reasons for adopting or not adopting the position that the quran has something concrete to say about reality.

Comment: @G.Bach that was just an intro and reminder for me to answer the question later ;)

Comment: @Medi1Saif i do not see any difference from possible questions in sites like physics and stackoverflow and history. do you think answers there are preaching truth and have not different opinion?! this is just a scientific/logical question. if you think that sites' answers are of one opinion, here also you can think people of one opinion, just one can A,G,P as proofs, another A,X,P as proofs, and another A,G,P,X, and they can do not copy answers that are already said, but just make addition to some of other answers.