# Are questions like "how do I know Islam is true" a matter of preaching Truth?

Tags: discussion, capital-t-truth

Sometimes, questions asking for proof that Islam is true ([here's a current one](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/38305/im-dating-a-muslim-woman-and-i-want-to-marry-her-but-im-agnostic)) come up; this is a question not about Islam per se, but about some logically prior meta-system of being convinced, something like rhetoric or epistemic philosophy, which leads to these questions:

- are questions asking how one can decide whether Islam is true on-topic?
- if they are, are they [Truth](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1591/how-can-we-discourage-users-from-using-the-site-to-preach-truth) questions? All answers to such questions I've come across are pretty much exclusively apologetics, which cannot be considered academic in any way.

If they are both on-topic and viable questions instead of Truth questions, does that imply that a long answer about how you can't know, or what arguments there are to say Islam isn't true would be acceptable, or is an assumption of "Islam is true" intended as site policy?