# What should be done about question 237?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, capital-t-truth

Going through the [late answers queue](https://islam.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/), the question "[Is listening to Music Halal (permissible) or Haram (prohibited) in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/237/22)" appears to have resurfaced. As an older question, written before we really ironed out what does and what does not work here, it is very obviously problematic.

The crux of this issue is, of course, the fact that it is unabashedly a Truth question; it establishes a clear difference of opinion, and asking which of the two interpretations is "correct", with absolutely no scope in which to frame any answer.

This is *exactly* the sort of problematic post discussed in the meta post "[Is there any way to make Truth questions constructive?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1442/22)"; if I saw this question posted today, I would close it in a heartbeat.

The problem (if you can call it that) is that the top-voted answer doesn't actually fall into the opinion-bait trap; it is reasonably neutral and explains not only the difference of opinion but the relative strengths of each opinion. Most importantly, it doesn't call out any one interpretation as "more correct".

Which is more than I can say about *every single other answer on the post*.

This is a question which I don't doubt is asked ad-nauseum on the Internet at large; having a strong canonical answer here is immensely valuable. However, as written, I don't think it's going to get any better; it'll likely just keep attracting Truth claims attempting to answer the *actual* question asked ("Is Music Halal (allowed) or Haram (prohibited)?")

What exactly should be done with this? Is there some way to re-work the question so that it actually works here? Should the weaker "Truthy" answers just be downvoted? Deleted? Should we just wash our hands of the whole thing and just historical-lock it?

Answer (score 1):

I actually think the question is just fine except for the last sentence. It nicely describes a difference of opinion that the OP discovered which he was curious about. The last sentence asks which opinion is "correct," which is not really an answerable question, as you note here. I would suggest changing that sentence to ask what the reason is for the difference of opinion and perhaps allow asking if one of the opinions is more widely-accepted than the other.

As for the answers, I would suggest editing a disclaimer into the ones that actually answer the question as it is *currently* saying that they answer an older version of the question which was changed per site guidelines.