# Authentic Answers of questions

Tags: discussion

This platform has been made is an awesome step towards people who would like to be answered to clear their doubts or to gain knowledge about what people are unaware of. But the issue is no one knows about the person answering is authentic or his answers are authentic. Pasting the Verses is easy, but explaining(tafseer of) those verses in correct content of knowledge requires expertise that is why we have 'ulma e karam(s), Aalim(s).. etc'. This responsibility is not eligible for any ordinary person. The person who have created this community should reach out to all the Ulma(s), Aalim(s) of all sects to join here and to handle these questions and give them special permissions on this community, as these questions are not just questions. These questions are about the people and answers going to affect them and their lives. Therefore answers should be correct and accurate. I shared an advice. Look up to it admins, please! it is really important or this place will be a mess.

Comment: What you are asking for seems partly not going ahead with the policies of stack exchange! We are not a fatwa site! Relevant posts https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/417/inviting-experts and http://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1815/giving-help-or-fatwa-or-advice-or-what

Answer (score 5):

The same can be said about *every single site on the Stack Exchange Network*: People shouldn't *ever* be soliciting answers from people who don't know what they're talking about. The whole *point* of the Stack Exchange model is to build a community of *experts* who *do* know enough to answer questions (or, at least, who know enough to know which questions they're *qualified* to answer), and through their collective voting determine which answers are good and which ones are bad. Peer review is *fundamental* to making this site work, and building a community of the *right* peers is *essential*.

There are 169 sites on Stack Exchange, most of which have developed their own expert communities simply by being places that actually encourage experts to participate. None of them needed admins to step in and *provide* experts, and none of them needed admins to step in and *empower* experts above and beyond the reputation-based privileges the system already provides.

The fact that this site is still lacking in experts is worrying, but that's a *community* problem, not an *administration* problem. Even if the admins *do* go out and bring in some experts, why would they want to stay here? What exactly does *this community* offer *them*? You want experts to come in and answer your questions authoritatively, but *what are they getting in return*?

In general, experts like to participate in communities where they can *get* as much as they *give*. You build a community of help vampires, where the only thing experts have to look forward to is answering questions from people who don't know enough to answer questions themselves and really can't be bothered to try, then yeah, experts are probably not going to stick around. That's boring.

As I read it, your post here *is* part of the problem: You're just recognizing a problem, but rather than put any effort into solving it yourself you're just asking others (i.e. the admins) to do it for you. If you want to attract experts, you need to work for it. There is no shortcut.

Comment: By admin(s) i meant the people who are in-charge of this community, and it was an advice for them to contact the experts and the experts i am talking about won't ask for anything in return as they will already be gaining a-lot spiritually, I'm not asking for them to stick around here. I just hope if they are introduced to this platform to answer the questions would be a much better approach. (1)

Comment: Down-vote for what reason though? it shows your approach towards this matter is limited, since it is you shouldn't involve or at-least don't down-vote it and why this question was migrated here? Your answer is partially, as it fits on other communities, but not for this one... (2)

Comment: @ARr0w The admins' job is to make sure users don't mess up the site, it's not their job to build the community; the community has to build itself. Experts need not be Muslim, so "gaining spiritually" does not apply to many experts. Muslim scholars wouldn't find this site interesting at the moment for a number of reasons; smallish audience, quibbling, sectarian infighting, a bunch of modernist-leaning users, other users get to criticize their positions - in my experience Muslim scholars really don't like that last one, it's bad adab for them to argue amongst themselves, much less with lay folk.

Comment: @ARr0w I suggest you take the time to go through our [tour] and our [help] to better understand the Stack Exchange model; your post and your comments here suggest you really don't understand how this site works or how we differ from a typical Internet forum. Then I would recommend you take the time to learn and study until *you* can actually answer questions properly so *you* can contribute to the site rather than just expecting other people do to it for you. If you care about this site *at all*, you can put the effort into setting a positive example that experts *will* respond to.